# Reset Windows user profile settings to default values

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8, windows-10, windows-10-upgrade

After I upgraded Windows 7 to Windows 10, the user account I use seems to be corrupted. For example, after I enabled Spotlight on that account, it doesn't let me disable it, and after I upgraded to 1511, after I log in it shuts down the PC. When I managed to log in, I noticed that the accent color was changed as well, and setting it to "Automatically pick an accent color from my background" didn't fix it.

I created a new account after the Windows 10 upgrade, and it doesn't have these problems, so my guess is that somehow the settings from Windows 7 have messed up my profile.

Microsoft's solution is to [delete the account](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/fix-corrupted-user-profile#1TC=windows-7) and start from scratch. I'm trying to avoid that, since I want to keep my application settings, and if I have to start from scratch, I might as well do a clean Windows 10 installation instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after messing up my profile thoroughly by using a tool designed for windows XP, I went ahead and followed Microsoft's advice and just created a new local account. I'm my case, it was painless enough, but I had to reinstall a few apps that I installed for just the other account instead of fire all users.

Marking this as the accepted answer, but if someone suggests a better solution in the future, I'll be interested in trying it out and accepting it.